# System unresponsive, but no CPU load

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, top

One of my servers is completely unresponsive:

```
top - 06:16:53 up  2:14,  1 user,  load average: 30.95, 29.96, 22.92
Tasks: 168 total,   2 running, 166 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us, 12.6 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id, 86.4 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  1.1 st
KiB Mem :  1014524 total,    61368 free,   877028 used,    76128 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.     4196 avail Mem 
  scroll coordinates: y = 1/168 (tasks), x = 1/12 (fields)
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                         
   30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S 11.1  0.0   4:04.70 kswapd0                                                                                                                                         
 1116 root      20   0  791548  44900      0 S  0.4  4.4   0:14.91 dockerd                                                                                                                                         
    1 root      20   0   37752   2664    864 D  0.2  0.3   0:06.00 systemd
```

It is difficult to say what is happening, since I can not really get much info (very unresponsive), but this is what I see:

- load average very high
- I see around 20% - 30% CPU load
- I do not see high IO / network utilization
- I can not identify what processes are in the run queue

How is it possible to have a high load average and low CPU utilization?

Answer (score 4):

You have run out of memory and the system is thrashing. There is not enough free memory to keep all the needed process pages in memory so the os must free some pages to be able to load in needed pages from disk. Since you have no swap, the pages to be freed cannot be written to swap space, so the only alternative is to either discard read-only code pages or shrink the buffer cache. When execution advances to a page that was discarded, it must be read into RAM again, at the expense of some other page. At some point the problem gets so bad that most of the time gets spent on waiting for pages to be loaded from disk and very few CPU cycles can be used for useful work.

Try adding some swap, although that may or may not help, depending on the load patterns of your processes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a mountpoint problem. When system is trying to mount a mountpoint that is not available at that time, it will start increasing system load though you might not experience there's some process hoarding CPU.

Try:

1. Running `mount` and see if there's some mountpoint that cannot be reached at that time.
2. Checking `/etc/fstab` for all mountpoints defined at start time and see if any of them cannot be reached at that time.